# why this code is not returning anything in C

Tags: c, return, return-value, return-type

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int u1,u2;
    
    printf("Enter two num : ");
    scanf("%d %d",&u1,&u2);

    return u1 == 30 || u2 == 30 || (u1+u2 == 30);
}
```

Question is : Write a C program to check two given integers, and return true if one of them is 30 or if their sum is 30.
I am new to Programming, If anyone Help me out what's wrong in this code. It should return 1 or True

Comment: When you say "the program is not returning anything", do you mean "the program is not creating any output in the terminal"?

Comment: I don't think ```main()``` returns to any other scope for the programmer to see what it returns?

Comment: You could in principle [check the program's exit code](https://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2008/03/how-to-check-exit-status-code.html) to see what value is returned from main(). Rohan, is that what you want to do?

Comment: Yes @RSahu..but now I got the solution. Thank You

Comment: Please share what exact problem you are facing instead of posting the complete [homework] problem

Comment: C is not the same as C++. See [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/). Read documentation of [printf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) and of [scanf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) and of the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler

Answer (score 1):

The return value is mapped to the process exit code. Normally `0` is success, so this will have a failure if that is logically true.

You may want to put this in a proper function and write a `printf` to display it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int compare()
{
    int u1,u2;
    
    printf("Enter two num : ");
    scanf("%d %d",&u1,&u2);

    return u1 == 30 || u2 == 30 || (u1+u2 == 30);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  printf("Result=%d\n", compare());

  return 0;
}
```

> Tip: Instead of taking interactive input notice how `argv` is like *right there* awaiting input as command-line arguments!